# Working with WebApi in a Web Forms application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to add WebApi in my Web Forms application (Visual Studio 2015, .NET 4.6). I added App_Start folder and WebApiConfig.cs in it as following (pretty much copied from an MVC app):

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Adding routes for WebApi controllers
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SearchApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/search",
            defaults: new { controller = "SearchController" }
            );

    }
}
```

Then, I created a folder Controllers/WebApi and added SearchController.cs:

```
namespace IdeaMaverick.Web.Controllers.WebApi
{
    public class SearchController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new [] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

But when I hit http://example.com/api/search in the browser, I get this error:

> {"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://www.example.com/api/search'.","messageDetail":"No type
>   was found that matches the controller named 'SearchController'."}

I'm obviously missing something but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue - in defaults for the route I had to specify the controller name omitting "Controller", so it has to be like

```
defaults: new { controller = "Search" }
```